# Update a choice field when an event occurs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want a `CharField` to automatically be updated into one of the choices it has when user clicks on a certain button. So I defined the model like this:

`models.py`:

```
class Oficio(models.Model):

    class Estatus(models.TextChoices):
        NUEVO = 'NU', _('Nuevo')
        NO_REVISADO = 'NR', _('No Revisado')
        LEIDO = 'L', _('Leido')
        SEGUIMIENTO = 'S', _('Seguimiento')
        COMPLETADO = 'C', _('Completado')

    folio = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, unique=True, null=False)
    usuario = ForeignKey('users.Usuarios', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    asunto = models.TextField(null=False)
    estatus = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Estatus.choices, default=Estatus.NUEVO)
    documento = models.FileField(upload_to='static/pdf')
    dependencia = models.ForeignKey('Dependencia', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dependencia_origen')
    turnado = models.ForeignKey('Dependencia', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dependencia_destino')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.folio
```

When creating a new object of this model, the `estatus` field default value is `Nuevo`.

In my template this object is displayed like this:[image: Object template]

And I want to update that `Nuevo` tag in blue into another one (one of the choices defined in `models.py`) when user clicks the button next to it which downloads the `documento` field file.

`template.html` for this button:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'oficios:status' oficio.folio %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" title="Descargar">
          <a href="{{oficio.documento.url}}" download>
              <i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>
          </a>
      </button>
</form>
```

So far I tried creating a function in `views.py` like this:

```
def change_status(request, pk):

    oficio = Oficio.objects.get(folio=pk)
    form_status = forms.UpdateStatus(instance=oficio)
    context = {'form_status': form_status}
    if oficio.estatus == 'NU':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            oficio.estatus = 'L'
            form_status = forms.UpdateStatus(request.POST, instance=oficio)
            if form_status.is_valid():
                instance = form_status.save(commit=False)
                instance.usuario = request.user
                instance.save()
                return redirect('oficios:list')
    return render(request, "oficios_confirmacion.html", context)
```

`forms.py`

```
class UpdateStatus(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Oficio
        fields = ['estatus']
```

But this function redirects me into another template in which the user must choose from the dropdown menu one of the choices for that field, like this:

[image]

It works fine but I want to stay into the first image template and change that field automatically when downloading the document by pressing the corresponding button. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.